# Auto close brackets, "", etc not working in new VSCode native jupyter notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying the new VSCode native Jupyter Notebook from the October Update. When I open .ipynb file and edit brackets aren't being closed automatically like on normal .py files. Is this intentional? Am I supposed to add my own settings to include autoclose brackets in VSCode?

Comment: Did you manage to make ir work?